# How to allow empty forms in a formset django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I want to check formset is empty or not. If empty, don't create new record in database. How can I do that?. Please help solve this problem although I entered required=False in the form.py. This is my code:

```
class ExtraValueFormRight(forms.ModelForm):
    label = forms.CharField(required=False,
                        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Sub Title'}))
    somevalue = forms.CharField(required=False,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Some Value'}))

class Meta:
    model = OrderHeader
    fields = ('label', 'somevalue')
```

HTML:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset.forms %}
     <div class='table-left'>
         <table class='no_error'>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                       {{ form.label }}
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="col-lg-12">
                        {{ form.somevalue }}
                   </div>
               </div>
          </table>
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Normally django ModelFormSet does exactly that (they won't create a new object in DB, if the user did not fill in the form). Can you show your forset creation code? (your view code, I guess). Note that in the template code, you are missing a {{ form.id }} for each form in the formset loop

Answer (score 0):

As you are using ModelForm, the properties of model field that you are using in you form will also effect validation of form. You should check whether `label` and `somevalue` can be null or not from you model properties. If you want to give some default value for empty field of your models, use `default` property in you model. You can also override `save` method of your form.

For making a field required,

```
class ExtraValueFormRight(forms.ModelForm):
    label = forms.CharField(required=True,
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Sub Title'}))
    somevalue = forms.CharField(required=True,
                        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Some Value'}))

class Meta:
    model = OrderHeader
    fields = ('label', 'somevalue')
```

Comment: I want to check formset is empty or not. If empty, don't create new record in database. How can I do that?

Comment: in your form field, set required=True. It will not allow you to submit empty form.